# Is there any way of programatically test-compiling Raku code?

Tags: syntax, compilation, raku

You can save code to a file and compile it with [`raku -c`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/wiki/Running-rakudo-from-the-command-line). Is there any way to do the same programatically, using some public API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an undocumented named parameter `:check` to `EVAL` that will prevent the compiled code from actually running.  It will return `Nil` on success.  If there are any errors, it will throw like it otherwise also would.

```
$ raku -e 'q/say "foo"/.EVAL'
foo

$ raku -e 'q/zay "foo"/.EVAL'
===SORRY!=== Error while compiling ...
Undeclared routine:
    zay used at line 1. Did you mean 'say'?

$ raku -e 'say q/say "foo"/.EVAL(:check)'
Nil
```

Perhaps that named parameter should be documented.

EDIT: Please note that this will *not* prevent `BEGIN` blocks from being run, as @ugexe pointed out.

Comment: `raku -e 'q/BEGIN say "foo"/.EVAL(:check)'`